# Rename the [local-storage] tag to be more language/implementation-specific

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [local-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-storage) tag's wiki states:

> Local Storage is a way to store persistent data using JavaScript. It should be used only with HTML5 compatible web browser.

However despite this the tag is seeing quite a few questions along the lines of *how do I store things locally?*. Here are two example questions which were both asked in the last 24 hours that I've edited the tag out of:

- [Xamarin Android - where to store images locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482712/xamarin-android-where-to-store-images-locally)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461309/windows-store-apps-secure-local-storage-solution

As you can see, neither of these are talking about JavaScript's local storage, but are instead asking about how to store images and PDFs on a system.

Would it be sensible to rename [local-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-storage) to be more language or implementation-specific, such as [javascript-local-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-local-storage) or [web-local-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-local-storage)?

I guess if that is changed it may also be appropriate to rename [session-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-storage) to [javascript-session-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-session-storage) or [web-session-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-session-storage) as well.